# Fitnesse: the instance decision table does not exist

Tags: fitnesse

```
!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}

!path D:\down\fitnesse-standalone.jar
!path D:\down\fitnesse.jar

!path D:\test\NewProject\bin\com\geekcap\fitnesse\fixtures
!define COLLAPSE_SETUP {true}  !define COLLAPSE_TEARDOWN {true}
|Import|
|com.geekcap.fitnesse.fixtures|
!|script|
!|MultiplicationFixture|
|operand1|operand2|product?|
|1|1|1|
|5|5|25|
```

I tried to run the preceding script in fitnesse but it returns:

```
"The instance decisionTable_2.setOperand1. does not exist".
```

please help me out , where i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Separate your tables with a blank line, and remove the `script` row.

```
|Import|
|com.geekcap.fitnesse.fixtures|

!|MultiplicationFixture|
|operand1|operand2|product?|
|1|1|1|
|5|5|25|
```